# Makefile: $(shell find ...) doesn't output correct results

Tags: java, makefile

```
ALL_SRC := $(shell find . -name "*.java")
ALL_CLASS = $(shell find . -name "*.class")

all:
    @echo "Compiling..."
    $(JAVAC) $(ALL_SRC)
    echo $(ALL_CLASS)
    find . -name "*.class"
```

When the class files exist at the time of running this makefile, `$(ALL_CLASS)` is correctly set.

How come `echo $(ALL_CLASS)` prints a blank while `find . -name "*.class"` returns all class files within the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class files don't exist when `make` starts running, `ALL_CLASS` will be set to blank because they're not there at the time the `shell find` is run.

However, your `find` on the last line is running *after* you compile all the Java files.

A simpler example may help, let's first create a file `xyzzy1`:

```
touch xyzzy1
```

Then use the following makefile, which is basically the same as yours in terms of when things are created and run:

```
XYZZY=$(shell ls xyzzy*)
all:
    echo ===
    touch xyzzy2
    echo $(XYZZY)
    echo ===
    ls xyzzy*
    rm xyzzy2
    echo ===
```

When you run `make` on that, you see:

```
===
xyzzy1
===
xyzzy1 xyzzy2
===
```

and that's because the execution of `XYZZY=$(shell ls xyzzy*)` happens *before* the `all` rule has started (so `xyzzy2` does not yet exist).

The `ls xyzzy*` within the `all` rule itself is executed *after* the `touch` and *before* the `rm` so both files exist at that point.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I thought "=" assignment, contrast to ":=" assignment, is evaluated at the time of using the variable. Is there a way to defer the evaluation of ALL_CLASS variable?

Comment: @yawnerish, I think it's just a misunderstanding. Deferred means it's not evaluated until it's _needed_ in the first pass, or when the second pass happens. It doesn't mean deferred until it's _used_ in the second pass.

Comment: One more question... How would you personally resolve this problem? What can I do so that $(ALL_CLASS) will fetch an up-to-date file listing? Just running `find . -name "*.class"` works, but I'd like to keep such a command at the top stored in a variable.

Comment: paxdiablo's comment above regarding deferred is slightly  misleading.  The reason this doesn't work is that make expands all variables in the entire recipe before it tries to run any commands in the recipe.  So, the value of ALL_CLASS is expanded before even the `echo "Compiling..."` statement is invoked.  That's why it's empty.

Comment: You can keep the command in a variable; set the variable to this: `ALL_CLASS = \`find . -name "*.class"\``.  Now whenever that variable is used it expands to the backquoted string, which the _shell_ will run rather than make.